# Angular field validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, intellij-idea

In my project I wanted to do a field validation. So I found a tutorial how to do it. Following the tutorial I got this code.

```js
var app = angular.module('RegistrationScreen', []);

 app.controller('RegistrationScreenController',  function($scope, $http) {
       $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: '/lt'
       }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.nameList = response.data.registrationNameTags;
        $scope.topics = response.data.topicList;
        $scope.bankDivisions = response.data.bankDivisionList;

        document.title =  response.data.registrationNameTags.title;
          });

 });
var applic = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages'])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="RegistrationScreen" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
        textarea { resize:none; }
    </style>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="js/registration.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="applic" ng-controller="RegistrationScreenController as main">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>{{ nameList.header }}</h1>
        </div>

        <form name="nameForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
            <div class="center-block">
                <div class="form-group"  ng-class="{ 'has-error': nameForm.name.$touched && nameForm.name.$invalid }">
                    <label for="inputName" ng-model="inputName" class="col-xs-3 control-label">{{ nameList.name }}</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputName"
                               ng-model="main.name"
                               ng-minlength="5"
                               ng-maxlength="10"
                               required>
                        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="nameForm.name.$error" ng-if="nameForm.name.$touched">
                            <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
                            <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
                            <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This should write "Your name is too short" if name is smaller than 5 symbols, "Your name is too long" if name is bigger than 10 symbols, "Your name is required" if there is nothing written. And if I meet the requirements error message should dissapear. Now to the problem. Problem is that if I write name that contains less than 5 symbols it still prints all 3 error messages. And after that if I meet the requirement error messages doesn't dissapear, instead they just change their color to grey. What am I doing wrong? 
Here are two screenshots how this code works.
[image: Error screenshot]
[image: After meeting requirements]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have little confusion with modules. Remove `ng-app="applic"` attribute and make single `RegistrationScreen` module with ngMessages dependency:

```
var app = angular.module('RegistrationScreen', ['ngMessages']);
```

Then you don't need `var applic = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages'])`;

Comment: Could you please explain why because of that it wasn't working?

Comment: Because you application never used ngMessages module necessary for ng-messages to show correctly. Angular find the first ng-app attribute and use it to bootstrap the app, so ng-app="applic" was ignored and hence you didn't have ngMessages available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation!